# 404 unauthorized : authenticate with the Realm CLI:

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

can anyone help me with this
every time i try to authenticate with the Realm CLI using the following command line :

```
realm-cli login --api-key="<my api key>" --private-api-key="<my private api key>"
```

401 Unauthorized: failed to authenticate: error: failed to authenticate with MongoDB Cloud API: You are not authorized for this resource.

any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you whitelisted yourself, and/or give yourself permission to access the db after generating your keys?

you could check [the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/reference/cli-auth-with-api-token/)

Comment: ok never mind , i found that i had to remove the less than and greater than signs around the public / private key